# About custom operations in Tensorflow and PyTorch

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, pytorch, torch

I have to implement an energy function, termed Rigidity Energy, as in Eq 7 of this paper [here](https://www.igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/arap_web.pdf).
The energy function takes as input two 3D object meshes, and returns the energy between them. The first mesh is the source mesh, and the second mesh is the deformed version of the source mesh. In rough psuedo-code, the computation would go like this:

Iterate over all the vertices in the source mesh.

1. For every vertex, compute its covariance matrix with its neighboring vertices.
2. Perform SVD on the computed covariance matrix and find the rotation matrix of the vertex.
3. Use the computed rotation matrix, the point coordinates in the original mesh and the corresponding coordinates in the deformed mesh, to compute the energy deviation of the vertex.

Thus this energy function requires me to iterate over each point in the mesh, and the mesh could have more than 2k such points. In Tensorflow, there are two ways to do this. I can have 2 tensors of shape (N,3), one representing the points of source and the other of the deformed mesh.

1. Do it purely using Tensorflow tensors. That is, iterate over elements of the above tensors using `tf.gather` and perform the computation on each point using only existing TF operations. This method, would be extremely slow. I've tried to define loss functions that iterate over 1000s of points before, and the graph construction itself takes too much time to be practical.
2. Add a new TF OP as explained in the TF documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op) . This involves writing the function in CPP (and Cuda, for GPU support), and registering the new OP with TF.

The first method is easy to write, but impractically slow. The second method is a pain to write.

I've used TF for 3 years, and have never used PyTorch before, but at this point I'm considering switching to it, if it offers a better alternative for such cases.

Does PyTorch have a way of implementing such loss functions both easily *and* performs as fast as it would on GPU. i.e, A pythonic way of writing my own loss functions that runs on GPU, without any C or Cuda code on my part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are essentially asking if this operation can be vectorized. The answer is no, at least not fully, because [svd](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.svd) implementation in PyTorch is not vectorized.

If you showed the tensorflow implementation, it would help in understanding your starting point. I don't know what you mean by finding the rotation matrix of the vertex, but I would guess this can be vectorized. This would mean that svd is the only non-vectorized operation and you could perhaps get away with writing just a single custom OP, that is the vectorized svd - which is likely quite easy, because it would amount to calling some library routines in a loop in C++.

Two possible sources of problems I see are

1. if the neighborhoods of `N(i)` in equation 7 can be of significantly different sizes (which would mean that the covariance matrices are of different sizes and vectorization would require some dirty tricks)
2. the general problem of dealing with meshes and neighborhoods could be difficult. This is an innate property of irregular meshes, but PyTorch has support for sparse matrices and a dedicated package [torch_geometry](https://rusty1s.github.io/pytorch_geometric/build/html/index.html), which at least helps.